# Manage Kubernetes Cluster from .Net

Tags: .net, kubernetes, deployment, azure-api-management

Is there any framework, library or api which can be used by .Net in order to manage an Azure Kubernetes Cluster programmatically?

For example:

1. Deploy StatefullSets
2. Deploy Services
3. Deploy Volumes
4. Deploy Ingresses
5. Get deployment statuses for each resource deployment
6. Sent Rest API Calls directly inside the cluster using Service FQDN (myservice.namespace.svc.cluster.local)

Comment: Maybe the REST API can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp

Comment: @Nikita Chayka you can post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following project - https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp
It provides C# client for most of Kubernetes APIs